# $E(e^{i t \xi}|\mathcal{A})=E(e^{ i t \xi})$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \xi$ is independent with $\mathcal{A}$ .

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, fourier-transform, conditional-expectation, independence

Here $\xi$ is some random variable on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, and $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{F}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra. Apparently, two conditions are sufficient and necessary to each other, but one direction is trivial. My idea is based on following result:

$\xi$ is independent with $\mathcal{A}$ $\iff$ $E(g(\xi)|\mathcal{A})=E(g(\xi))$ for all bounded measurable $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Certainly, the condition "bounded measurable" can be loosened, but the hard part is how to get such a family from the approximation of $\{e^{it(\cdot)}\}$.

So far, I've come up with:

1. **Inverse Fourier transform** together with some Fubini trick. However, Fourier inversion theorem requires $\xi$ to possess good properties, at least $\xi$ must have density function. That's not the case here.
2. **Fourier series**. However, Fourier series only converges inside a compact interval. To be more precise, a Fourier series $s_n$ that consists of terms in $\{e^{ix(\cdot)}\}$ satisfies $s_n\to g$ pointwise or $L^2$ on supp($g$). We hope that $E(s_n(\xi)|\mathcal{A})=E(s_n(\xi))$ would give us $E(g(\xi)|\mathcal{A})=E(g(\xi))$, which involves taking limit under the integral. However, we only have $s_n\to g$ on supp($g$), not on $\mathbb{R}$.

Do you have other ideas to prove this one?

Comment: Hint: It's enough to show for the case that $g(x) = 1_{[a,b]}(x)$ for $a < b$.

Comment: @user6247850: I am aware of that. There are many kinds of conditions can be put on $g$. But what's next?

Comment: I think @user6247850 wants you to express $g$ as a limit of simple functions.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yes, but we have to prove the case of simple functions first.